# ActiveRecord finder method #where not filtering query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, class-method, activerecord-relation

**TL;DR**: *Why am I receiving a list of all resident's when I'm using class methods to scope between active & inactive residents?*

My application uses the ['acts_as_tenant' gem](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant). The tenant model is called Account, which has many employees who manage residents.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_subdomain

  has_one  :admin, class_name: 'Employee', foreign_key: :account_id, 
    dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :account

  has_many :employees, class_name: 'Employee', foreign_key: :account_id, 
    dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :account

  has_many :residents
  has_many :invites
  has_many :daily_summaries
  has_one  :subscription
  .
  .
  .
end
```

In my resident's schema there is a flag attribute named `is_active`, it's purpose being to differentiate between active and soft-deleted residents. You can also see the db constraints added.

```
create_table :residents do |t|
  t.integer    :account_id, null: false
  t.integer    :employee_id, null: false
  t.boolean    :is_active, default: true, null: false
  .
  .
  .
end
```

I allow employees to view soft-deleted residents & offer a tabbed index-view of both active/inactive residents.

[image]

In my Resident class I have the following class methods to scope based on active/inactive state.

```
  class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_tenant(:account)
    .
    .
    .
    def self.inactive_count(current_account)
      where({ account_id: current_account.id, is_active: false }).count
    end

    def self.default(current_account)
      where({ account_id: current_account.id, is_active: true })
    end

    def self.inactive(current_account)
      # where({ account_id: current_account.id, is_active: false })
      where("account_id = ? AND is_active = ?", current_account.id, false).first 
    end

    def archive
      update_attribute(:is_active, false)
    end
    .
    .
    .
  end
```

**My problem** is that I am receiving a list of all residents in both the active and inactive tabs in my index-view. Note the last name is the same in both images of this view page.

[image]

**I would prefer** for the class method to only return active or inactive residents respectively.

I'm wanting to find out why I'm not receiving only active or only inactive residents based on my query class methods.

The class methods for active/inactive count appear to be working as expected, here is a peak.

```
  def index
   @inactive_residents = Resident.inactive(current_account)
   @inactive_resident_count = Resident.inactive_count(current_account)
   @active_residents = Resident.default(current_account)
   @active_resident_count = Resident.active_count(current_account)
  end
```

**My reading so far to solve**:

- [Rails Guides - ActiveRecord querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)
- [Rails scope returns all instead of nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942672/rails-scope-returns-all-instead-of-nil)
- [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-values)

**Server logs included to show SQL**

[image]

**View templates**

index.html.erb

```
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">
      Active Residents&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="badge badge-purple">
        <%= @active_resident_count %>
      </span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">
       Inactive Residents&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <span class="badge badge-dark">
         <%= @inactive_resident_count %>
       </span>
     </a>
   </li>
```

_active_residents.html.erb

```
<% if @active_residents.any? %>
  <tbody>
    <% @active_residents.reverse_each do |resident| %>
      .
      .
      .
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
<% end %>
```

_inactive_residents.html.erb

```
<% unless @inactive_residents.nil? %> 
  <% @inactive_residents.reverse_each do |resident| %>
    .
    .
    .
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Update after comment**

My logs are below, nothing changes in the log when I select the 'inactive' tab in the browser. I also don't see any output from js console in dev tools unless I set an option for verbose output. I will include an image of this also.
[image: Logfile pt.1]

[image: Logfile pt.2]

[image]

Comment: could be a UI/jQuery issue. See if you are rendering the correct data under each tab. Since the count looks correct.

Comment: Thanks @emaillenin, you were correct! If you copy/paste your comment into an answer I will accept it as you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a UI/jQuery issue. See if you are rendering the correct data under each tab. Since the count looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me**

[Second comment in Yan Foto's answer to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542885/render-rails-partial-forms-using-nav-bar-tabs-in-bootstrap)

To sum up the link above:

> if you are using the `data-attribute` method you have to have the `href` attribute set to the ID of the tab you want to open. In JS version you have to have something like `$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show')` in order to open a tab with href value set to #profile

**My example**

in both partial files I added

`<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="my_tab1_id">`

and in index.html.erb which houses the partials I changed the `href` value from `#` to `my_tab_id`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-right">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#my_tab1_id" data-toggle="tab">
      Active Residents&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="badge badge-purple">
        <%= @active_resident_count %>
      </span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="#my_tab2_id" data-toggle="tab">
       Inactive Residents&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <span class="badge badge-dark">
         <%= @inactive_resident_count %>
       </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```